# Android Barcode Scanner and NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc, barcode

Scenario: I have an android app use to scan both Barcodes and NFC.

The application to scan barcodes came with the scanner from Famoco http://www.famoco.com/new-product-launch-fx200-fx300/ but not the NFC reader.

So, what I did was simply implemented an old NFC project into the build-in barcode reader application. Everything works fine, the only problem is, the NFC takes about 2-3 seconds to output the result because the application still runs the barcode reader when I tap to read an NFC tag.

So I was wondering if there's a way to not call the Barcode Intent when I call the NFC and vice-versa.

As I understand, the onPause() is called first then onResume() then newIntent() but whatever I try doesn't seem to work. I even tried putting an String Extra on the intent to retrieve the top most intent but this didn't work neither.

I tried adding a flag right after the NFC to not continue, but that causes the Barcode not work the next time around after using the NFC.

Please help....

Here's what my code is like

```
// Called with the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyApplication.getInstance().acquireWakeLock(this);
    mainScreen();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // sound
    tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
    chBeep.setChecked(beepMode);

}

// check if nfc is detected
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDecode)).setText(
                                                    ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
       //THIS IS NOT WORKING AND CAUSE THE BARCODE TO STOP AFTER I RUN NFC
        /*isNFC = true*/            
    }
}

//Function to decode the NFC to String    
private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) {
    int i, j, in;
    String[] hex = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    String out = "";

    for (j = inarray.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];

    }
    return out;

}

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // disabling foreground dispatch:
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

        if (bcr != null) {
            setIdle();
            bcr.release();
            bcr = null;
        }
    }

// Called when the activity is about to start interacting with the user.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        // creating pending intent:
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                        new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        // creating intent receiver for NFC events:
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        // enabling foreground dispatch for getting intent from NFC event:
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[] { filter }, this.techList);

        //THIS IS NOT WORKING AND CAUSE THE BARCODE TO STOP AFTER I RUN NFC
        /*if(isNFC)
            return;*/  

        // Bar code reader
        state = STATE_IDLE;

        try {
            dspStat(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " v"
                                            + this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18)
                bcr = BarCodeReader.open(getApplicationContext()); // Android
            else
                bcr = BarCodeReader.open(); // Android 2.3

            if (bcr == null) {
                dspErr("open failed");
                return;
            }
            bcr.setDecodeCallback(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dspErr("open excp:" + e);
        }

        bcr.setParameter(765, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Why not have it in a different activity?

Comment: That was my original thought, but the boss wants it to be in the same activity without having to flip between one and the other one. Because they have about 5000 scans to do and it would be long to flipping each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can scan NFC and Barcode in one activity, if you use custom Barcode scan Activity such as google mobile vision API.

https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/BarcodeCaptureActivity.java

In this activity, you can add module to scan NFC card. So when scan NFC, you can stop to scan Barcode and vice versa. In your project, there will be 2 functions. One is onNewIntent when NFC is scanned, other is onBarcodeDetected when Barcode is scanned.

Hope it will be helpful for you. Thanks.